# How to connect a frontend js file (that interacts with the dom) to an html/ejs file while also using nodejs/express

Tags: javascript, express

I am having issues trying to figure out how to take the functionality from a javascript file that uses DOM manipulation and then also connect it to the backend using express/nodejs.

I have tried linking it directly to the index.html file using the public folder. I was hoping people who have worked with both the backend and frontend could clarify this process for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend. I found this [simple example](https://itnext.io/learn-how-full-stack-apps-work-by-building-a-simple-one-using-javascript-part-1-38e237694012) searching for `plain javascript full stack small example`: